# Meaning of "Mythical Distance"

Tags: meaning, idioms

In this sentence

> With the break-up of the Roman Empire and the rise of Christianity, Europe saw India recede into a *mythical distance*

Is *mythical distance* an idiom? What does it mean?

Comment: It means that Europe starting perceiving India as a land that exists in myths  and stories, with giant palaces and Rajahs and tigers, instead of a real, physical place, with real, physical people, living real, physical lives. Presumably the context is the post-Colonial era where political and trade ties necessarily attentuated a bit, and India was much less visible in the European eye and day-to-day life. Anyway, if you think of the reality, the here-&-now where we live, as "close", and picture the mists of history and legend *waaay* over there, then *India receded into the mythical distance*.

Comment: It is not post colonial but after rise of Christianity, hope this will clarify the context.

Comment: The idea is the same. Did my comment clear up your doubts?

Comment: If you look up "mythical distance" in a Google search, you might be confused because the phrase is used in different ways.  Dan has the interpretation that fits here.

Comment: @DanBron your comment does clarifies the idea. Please make it an answer. Also reply my another silly question along with it whether it is idiom or is it a phrase?

Comment: @Ramaprakasha The standards of evidence are such on this site that I can't just copy/paste that comment as an answer, I'd have to put in more time and effort than I have available to me to substantiate it (though I am currently [running a little experiment](http://j.mp/1MiBg1l) to test the limits of that policy). You are welcome to post your own answer to your own question, however, and you may feel completely free to quote me, with or without attribution. And the sentence is just that, a sentence, and the words "mythical distance" are just a pair of words. Not an idiom or set phrase.

Comment: After the breakup of the Roman Empire, Europe descended into barbarism and widespread illiteracy.  India was too far away to impinge on Europe in any real way, except perhaps for the occasional exotic item of trade.  Europe was busy with Goths and Moors and fighting other Europeans.  What culture there was was preserved in monasteries; monks weren't interested in India.

Comment: Think of "mythic" as a synonym of "epic" or "legendary" in this context; it merely means something is so vast that it hearkens back to older eras of exaggerated grandeur.

Answer (score 2):

As Dan Bron's comment (above) indicates, the idea underlying "mythical distance" is that at some point after direct experience of a distant place ceases, the popular understanding of what that place is like, what creatures live there, how it is ruled, etc., becomes so encrusted with exaggerations, misconceptions, and fantasies that the account is more mythological than real. Knowledge of the place (in this case, India) recedes through loss of contact and communication, leaving—especially in a predominantly illiterate culture—only garbled tales as sources of local knowledge.

There is no better place to see examples of the effects of mythical distance than in the [*Histories* of Herodotus](https://books.google.com/books?id=8OdLLZ8S0uAC&pg=PA149&lpg=PA149&dq=mythological+creatures+%22Herodotus%22&source=bl&ots=ez0-IoTG5P&sig=XhXoo_PFaJO1JcSSgTYDb3MT-_Y&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjcyO-50rjSAhVN-mMKHe8wDs84ChDoAQggMAE#v=onepage&q=headless&f=false), who gamely passes along reports of dog-headed humans and headless beasts whose eyes are in their chests living in the region east of Libya, winged serpents in Arabia, gold-gathering ants the size of foxes living in Persia, cyclopes and griffins in northern Europe, a race of entirely bald humans living beyond Scythia, and a race of humans in southern India whose semen is black.

The tendency to ascribe outlandish customs and natural and unnatural wonders to  faraway places is certainly not unique to Europe, but I suspect that it has significantly influenced Western thought. In English, the very word *outlandish*—now a synonym for *bizarre*—began as a synonym for *foreign*.

Answer (score 1):

To build on @DanBron. The phrase "mythical distance" often refers to an oblique perception of cultural distance. In cultural studies, the distance often suggests a gap, growing or not, that has been constructed (or promoted) as the foundation for asymmetrical power-relations (control).

The means are through a structural discourse (literature, policy, etc.) that presents those people who are targeted at a distance, as curiously different (the "other") and desirable, and definitively not equal-- often referred to as the postcolonial gaze. Distance here is not necessarily physical, though that can influence.

The distance between New Zeeland and Britain, for example, is shorter than the one between, say, France and Papua new Guinea. Within the European historical studies about India, it fits within what Edward Said termed as "[Orientalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientalism)." As Don Baron wrote, a place that "exists in myths and stories."

The term also refers to the distorted view that derives from a lack of concrete knowledge between individuals, communities, and nations. [Beidelman](https://books.google.com/books?id=FRT-AQAAQBAJ&pg=PA337&dq=%E2%80%9CMythical%20Distance%E2%80%9D&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiuhP_j2oLNAhXF1h4KHViiBFsQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%9CMythical%20Distance%E2%80%9D&f=false) defines it as the distance that "produces a sort of inverted image, which to Douglas's common-sense approach must look rather like the unreality of a mirage, and an upside-down mirage at that."